# ngResource and SPA angularjs not displaying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I am having a problem with angular ngResource. When I add the dependency the pages are not populated.. Here is my code :

```
/*var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('todoFactory', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/meetups');
});*/

angular.module('myApp').controller('loginController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.login = function () {

      // initial values
      $scope.error = false;
      $scope.disabled = true;

      // call login from service
      AuthService.login($scope.loginForm.username, $scope.loginForm.password)
        // handle success
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/');
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.loginForm = {};
        })
        // handle error
        .catch(function () {
          $scope.error = true;
          $scope.errorMessage = "Invalid username and/or password";
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.loginForm = {};
        });    
    };    
}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('logoutController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService', '$resource',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.logout = function () {

      // call logout from service
      AuthService.logout()
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/login');
        });    
    };   

/*

 $scope.posts = [];
   $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', create_at: ''};

    $scope.afficher = function(){
      $scope.newPost.created_at = Date.now();
      $scope.posts.push($scope.newPost);
      $scope.newPost = {created_by: '', text: '', created_at: ''};
  };    
*/
   $scope.meetups = [];
  /*var Meetup = $resource('/api/meetups');

  Meetup.query(function (results) {
    $scope.meetups = results;
  });

  $scope.meetups = []

  $scope.createMeetup = function () {
    var meetup = new Meetup();
    meetup.name = $scope.meetupName;
    meetup.$save(function (result) {
      $scope.meetups.push(result);
      $scope.meetupName = '';
    });
  }*/
}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('registerController',
  ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService',
  function ($scope, $location, AuthService) {

    $scope.register = function () {

      // initial values
      $scope.error = false;
      $scope.disabled = true;

      // call register from service
      AuthService.register($scope.registerForm.username, $scope.registerForm.password)
        // handle success
        .then(function () {
          $location.path('/login');
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.registerForm = {};
        })
        // handle error
        .catch(function () {
          $scope.error = true;
          $scope.errorMessage = "Something went wrong!";
          $scope.disabled = false;
          $scope.registerForm = {};
        });    
    };    
}]);
```

The problem occurs when I uncomment the first part of the code. I accept any suggestion or information I am really stuck so please help me. I will add code on demand.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create your module

```
angular.module('appName',[/*dependancies*/]
```

once you create it you can use it to create controller, or directive by

```
angular.('appName').controller(.... or ngular.('appName').directive
```

so first un-comment first code part and then find solution for error there. and may be you have not added the script reference for ngResource in your html file.
make sure you have add it just after script reference  to angular.

Comment: 10x for the reply i have added the script reference. i uncommented the first part it doesnt display anything and i dont get any errors on the console...please help

Answer (score 0):

$resource is missing in your log out controller & in your factory.

Also make sure you have angular-resource js in your project/html.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

app.factory('todoFactory', ['$resource' , function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/meetups');
}]);




   angular.module('myApp').controller('logoutController',
      ['$scope', '$location', 'AuthService', '$resource',
      function ($scope, $location, AuthService,$resource) //here.
{

        $scope.logout = function () {

          // call logout from service
          AuthService.logout()
            .then(function () {
              $location.path('/login');
            });    
        };   
    }
```